# Coinbase has the address of a bitcoin stored on a blockchain account. How do I access it?

Tags: transactions, wallet, coinbase.com

I don't have the login to the Blockchain account that I stored the bitcoin on. I do have proof of the purchase and transaction of the coin and the coins address, as it is stored on Blockchain. How can I retrieve the coin from Blockchain back into my wallet on Coinbase ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that you have a a blockchain.info/.com wallet.

You will have to log into the wallet and initiate a transaction.

If you cannot do that, and you do not have a wallet backup, then you are likely out of luck, the coins would be effectively lost.

You could attempt to contact their customer service to see if they can somehow let you log into the account.